# Get data from a JSON Array

Tags: json, elixir, elixir-poison

I have a JSON array:

```ex
response = [
  %{
    "created_at" => 1542757526,
    "email" => "bcs@yahoo.com",
    "first_name" => "rana",
    "id" => "YW1pcnBheWFyeUB5YWhvby5jb20=",
    "last_clicked" => nil,
    "last_emailed" => nil,
    "last_name" => "amir",
    "last_opened" => nil,
    "updated_at" => 1542759123
  },
  %{
    "created_at" => 1542757457,
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "first_name" => "rana",
    "id" => "cmFtaXIyNDI2QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==",
    "last_clicked" => nil,
    "last_emailed" => nil,
    "last_name" => "amir",
    "last_opened" => nil,
    "updated_at" => 1542759001
  },
  # .......
]
```

I'm trying to get the `email` field of all items in the `response` variable. Example:

```ex
["bcs@yahoo.com", "xyz@gmail.com", ....]
```

Comment: Can you show any code that you have tried? What part of your code is having the problem?

Comment: yeah when I tired 

    `Enum.flat_map(response, fn(c) -> c["email"] end)`

getting this error:

`(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "bcs@yahoo.com". This protocol is implemented for: DBConnection.PrepareStream, DBConnection.Stream, Date.Range, Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Stream, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet, Postgrex.Stream, Range, Stream, Timex.Interval`

Answer (score 2):

**You're looking for [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2).** This method calls the passed function on every item in the given list/enumerable:

```ex
Enum.map(response, fn item -> item["email"] end )
```

Alternatively, you can use the shorthand and make it concise:

```ex
Enum.map(response, &(&1["email"]))
```

---

<sup>**External Resources:** See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) and [also this](https://medium.com/jsguru/javascript-functional-programming-map-filter-and-reduce-846ff9ba492d) to understand the concept of *mapping* in functional programming in general.</sup>

<sup>**Side note:** `flat_map/2` is a variation of `map/2` that expects the "mapped result" to be another list (so it can be joined and flattened with the rest of the mapped results).</sup>

Comment: thanks to saving my life...
could you please elaborate me this function?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to map, you could also look at [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html). Essentially they combine the functionality of [Enum.map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) & [Enum.filter/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2).

They allow you to do something like this:

```
for %{"email" => email} <- response, do: email
```

or this:

```
for item <- response, do: item["email"]
```

**Note** there's a subtle difference in behavior between the result of the two: the former will filter out any items that do not match the left-hand side (it will only keep maps with an `"email"` key), but the latter will map the items lacking an email to `nil`.